# How to bind data once selected from search using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have search functionality on one of the field once user finished search and selected the value from the data grid i am populating value into field, So I am printing value in console correctly `console.log($scope.challengesDTO.chlgOwner)` but its not binding it to view model `challengesDTO.chlgOwner`

main.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
    <label for="chlgOwner" class="col-md-4">Challenge Initiated on behalf of:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chlgOwner" 
            ng-model="challengesDTO.chlgOwner" ng-click="openChallengerSearch()"
            name="chlgOwner"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

searchCtrl.js

```
$scope.selectedChallenger = function(workerObj) {
        $scope.challengesDTO.chlgOwner = workerObj.fullName;
        $scope.challengesDTO.chlgKey = workerObj.workerKey;
        console.log($scope.challengesDTO.chlgOwner);
        $scope.viewChallengeWin.close();
    };
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?? Just try to give `ng-model="challengesDTO"` to input like http://jsfiddle.net/de5hpx8v/

Comment: I think in this instance you may need to use `ng-bind` as opposed to `ng-model`

Comment: @bilpor **ng-model** should also work. Its **Two-Way** binding.

Comment: `ng-model` only gives two-way binding if inside a form, although the class has form-control set against it we cannot see if the whole <div> tag is in a form element.

Comment: @Manwal I am not getting any error , value is printed in console

Comment: @bilpor I can not use ng-bind i have to save form once values is selected

Comment: One thing to look at (debugging). Use something like the chrome debugger. Before you press submit, but have selected the value you want, look at $scope to see if the value you have selected is on the $scope object before submit. You need to try and narrow at what point the error seems to occur.